# Реализация своего ArrayList

Tags: java

Здравствуйте,есть задача написать свою коллекцию,но не понимаю как подойти к этому,как создать динамический массив в котором будут храниться все данные?

Comment: Так же советую посмотреть родную имплементацию http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java. Только, раз уж это задача в целях обучения - суть не с том, чтобы скопировать, а в том, чтобы понять, разобраться

Comment: Спасибо,вроде как "Лед тронулся",коллекции использовать нельзя,проблему с массивом я решил так:
-обьявил в классе массив типа Object(без инициализации)
 в методе add сделал переменную String куда добавляю через пробел все данные,и потом через split(" ")добавляю все в массив.
Скажите,это нормальное решение?

Comment: Ну, это решение, но, конечно, это больше костыль, не универсально, короче плохо. Не надо исользовать коллекции, можно использовать просто c-style массивы, их ява и использует по факту. Если и их нельзя использовать, то нужно реализовывать такую вещь как linked list. Тут каждый элемент хранит ссылку на предыдущий и последующий, а личт хранит ссылку на конец и начало. Но это сложнее и думаю, что от тебя ождают именно реализацию типа ArrayList

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Основные методы и логика масштабирования внутреннего массива в обе стороны:

```
public class MyArrayList<T> {
   private final int INIT_SIZE = 16;
   private final int CUT_RATE = 4;
   private Object[] array = new Object[INIT_SIZE];
   private int pointer = 0;

   /*
   Добавляет новый элемент в список. При достижении размера внутреннего
   массива происходит его увеличение в два раза.
   */
   public void add(T item) {
     if(pointer == array.length-1)
        resize(array.length*2); // увеличу в 2 раза, если достигли границ
     array[pointer++] = item;
   }

   /*
   Возвращает элемент списка по индексу.
   */
   public T get(int index) {
      return (T) array[index];
   }

   /*
   Удаляет элемент списка по индексу. Все элементы справа от удаляемого 
   перемещаются на шаг налево. Если после удаления элемента количество    
   элементов стало в CUT_RATE раз меньше чем размер внутреннего массива, 
   то внутренний массив уменьшается в два раза, для экономии занимаемого 
   места.
   */
   public void remove(int index) {
      for (int i = index; i<pointer; i++) 
        array[i] = array[i+1];
      array[pointer] = null;
      pointer--;
      if (array.length > INIT_SIZE && pointer < array.length / CUT_RATE) 
         resize(array.length/2); // если элементов в CUT_RATE раз меньше чем 
                                 // длина массива, то уменьшу в два раза
   }
   /*Возвращает количество элементов в списке*/
   public int size() {
      return pointer;
   }

   /*Вспомогательный метод для масштабирования.*/
   private void resize(int newLength) {
      Object[] newArray = new Object[newLength];
      System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, pointer);
      array = newArray;
   }      
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Для начала, прочитайте про Обобщения(Generics) в Java - это нужно для того, чтобы понять, как сделать коллекцию для любого типа.

Позже, на основании массива (ведь ArrayList и реализован на основе массива) сделайте динамическое расширение массива при достижении максимальной длины. Делается это в двух словах так:

1. Проверяете при добавлении не последний ли это элемент в массиве?
2. Если true -> создаете новый массив с бОльшим размером, чем в текущем, копируете содержимое текущего массива, а затем подменяете ссылки на массивы.

Таким же образом можно создавать динамически расширяемые стэки, очереди, etc.

Если нужны коллекции не на основе массива - смотрите в сторону LinkList или Tree, в интернете есть масса статей, как сделать свою коллекцию на основании LinkList или Tree.

p.s. Если нужно - есть исходники с LinkList и Tree, которые мы проходили в универе ;)

upd. [Исходники с некоторыми объяснениями на list и tree.](https://yadi.sk/d/3V0ynOVBxhGV7)

Comment: `p.s. Если нужно - есть исходники...` - ну так выложите их! Смысл вместо самого кода давать какие-то гарантии по его предоставлению? Ну или уберите этот раззадоривающий любопытство постскриптум.

Comment: @Arhad добавил ссылку, можете ознакомиться.

Answer (score 7):

Если не знаете как решить задачу целиком разбейте ее на подзадачи:

1. Создайте класс обертку для обычного массива
2. Реализуйте методы добавления, удаления и пр. Если вы хотите создать "честную" коллекцию, то нужно реализовать интерфейс `java.util.Collection` или `java.util.List`
3. Реализуйте динамическое увеличение размера, если в массиве не хватает места для следующего элемента. Это делается, обычно, созданием нового массива большего размера и копированием в него элементов из старого.
4. Добавьте дженерики.

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать имплементацию (реализация интерфейса) от List к своему классу, который реализует коллекцию типа ArrayList, чтобы не забыть реализовать нужные тебе методы.