# Коллекция с целыми числами, сложение и вычитание элементов

Tags: java, коллекции

Всем доброго времени суток! Учусь Java, пытаюсь понять, есть задание. Хотелось бы понять в каком направлении двигаться и правильно ли я мыслю. задание таково:

Необходимо создать коллекцию, которая хранит целые числа.
Функционал:

1. Добавление и удаление объектов по значению и по индексу. (Здесь лучше всего использовать LinkedList? Верно?)
2. При добавлении - все элементы коллекции увеличиваются на значение добавленного элемента (сложение)
3. При удалении - все элементы коллекции уменьшаются на значение удалённого элемента (вычитание)

в последних двух надо использовать цикл for each? Но я не понимаю, как именно его лучше всего использовать. Проблема скорее с логикой, не совсем могу перестроить мозг на это. Понимаю, что лучше использовать оберточный тип данных... Подскажите пожалуйста, верно ли мыслю, может покажите пример какой-нибудь? Гуглил.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Реализация своего ArrayList](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582919/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-arraylist)

Answer (score 2):

Пишу схематично чисто по постановке задачи.

```
class MyCollection<K extends Numbers> impliment IMyCollection{
     private Map<K,Integer> in = new HashMap<>();
     private Map<Integer,K> out= new HashMap<>();
     private bufferValue = 0;

     public K getValueFromIndex(int index){
         return out.get(index) + bufferValue;
     }
     public int getIndexFromValue(K value){
         return in.get(value - bufferValue);
     }

     public void setValueForIndex(int index, K value){
         value -= bufferValue;
         K oldvalue = out.get(index);
         if (oldvalue  != null){
             in.remove(oldvalue);
             bufferValue -= oldvalue;
         }
         in.put(value,index);
         out.put(index,value);
         bufferValue += value;
     }

     public void removeValueFromIndex(int index){
         K oldvalue = out.get(index);
         if (oldvalue == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not set!");
         bufferValue -= oldvalue;
         in.remove(oldvalue);
         out.remove(index);
     }
     public void removeIndexFromValue(K value){
         Integer oldindex = out.get(index);
         if (oldindex == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not set!");
         out.remove(oldindex);
         bufferValue -= value;
         in.remove(value);
     }

}
```

Дальше можете доработать под свою задачу. Сложность всех операций O(1).